# async actions with promises and redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to get updateValuesRouting called first - when the value is changed, I want a completely independent action called (after updateValuesRouting is completely finished executing) in publishRouting. Problem is, if I take out the timeout from the code below, the database gets screwy, and my api calls no longer work:

```
export function publishRouting(routingID, versionID, un, values){
    const url = `${ROOT_ROUTINGS_URL}/${routingID.trim()}/${versionID.trim()}/publish?username=${un}`;
    console.log("publish url:::",url);
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: PUBLISH_ROUTING_LOADING, isLoading:true});
        dispatch(updateValuesRouting(values, routingID)).then(
            setTimeout(() => {
                axios.put(url)
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        console.log("publish data returned:::", data);
                        dispatch(alertMessage("success", `${routingID} has been published!`));
                        dispatch(goToRouting(data.routingID, "000", history));
                        //window.location.reload();
                        dispatch({type: PUBLISH_ROUTING_SUCCESS, data}) ;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        dispatch(alertMessage("danger", `${routingID} failed with the following: ${err}`));
                        dispatch({type: PUBLISH_ROUTING_FAILURE, isCheckedOut: false, err})
                        console.log("publish error:", err);
                    })
            }, 500)
        );
    };
}

export function updateValuesRouting(values, routingID ){
    const url = `${ROOT_ROUTINGS_URL}/${routingID.trim()}/editing/meta`;
    console.log("routing url:: ",url, values);
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_VALUE_ROUTING_LOADING, isLoaded: false});
        return axios.put(url, values)
            .then(({data}) => {
            console.log("returned values from updateValuesRouting:",data);
                let myKeys = Object.keys(data);
                let ind;
                ind= myKeys.findIndex((x)=>{return x === 'headers'});
                myKeys.splice(ind, 1);
                ind= myKeys.findIndex((x)=>{return x === 'lastEditedDate'});
                myKeys.splice(ind, 1);
                ind= myKeys.findIndex((x)=>{return x === 'routingEditorMetaKey'});
                myKeys.splice(ind, 1);
                myKeys = myKeys.toString();
                dispatch(alertMessage("success", `${routingID} has updated ${myKeys}!`));
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_VALUE_ROUTING, data, isLoaded:true});

                return Promise.resolve();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch(alertMessage("danger", `${routingID} has not updated values. ${err}`));
                dispatch({type: UPDATE_VALUE_ROUTING_FAILURE, isLoaded: true})
            })
    }
}
```

With the timeout everything functions correctly, but I cannot ensure the timeout is valid amount of time for the server. Clearly I would like the promise to fully complete. How can I check for isLoaded to be true for the updateValuesRouting to ensure I am safe to make my next axios call and refresh my values from the server?

Comment: You don't show where `publishRouting()` is being called from, so it's hard for us to figure out an issue where it's being called in the wrong order. However, couldn't you call `publishRouting()` from within `updateValuesRouting()`, at the very end of the function?

Comment: I need to call updateValuesRouting within publishRouting, because updateValuesRouting is used in other places to update single values.  publishRouting is causing the db to update values from an editing mode into a final production mode when ready. But needs to update a value before publishing. Where publishRouting is called does not matter, it is not in the wrong order. Calling publishRouting just kicks off what you see above.

Comment: No one has an idea of how redux calls the promise on an axios request?